# Cannot connect to virtual machine

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, virtualbox, ping

I am working on Ubuntu machine, and created virtual Windows XP machine in Virtual Box 3.2 I cannot ping it.

Regardless if I set virtual machine Network (in Settings) to `Bridged` or `Host-only`, I can ping my real (ubuntu) machine from the virtual one, but I can't ping virtual one from the real one. Why is that and what can I do to be able to connect to virtual machine from the real one?

Comment: Have you enabled the firewall in Windows XP?  This may be blocking the pings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ptolemy's answer in the comments is probably correct, but there are other things you can check. First, are the IPs in the same network? Does arp work? (You can check this by doing `arp -an` in ubuntu, and just `arp -a` in Windows.) If they both list each other's IP and MAC, then you almost certainly have connectivity and the issue is just a firewall problem.